# iOS 8 TestFlight does not install app

Tags: ios

So as the title says, I am trying to pre-release an ios8 app. The app is uploaded successfully from the archive and appears under pre-release. I press on submit for beta release and add internal test users. In testflight the app appears, but when I press install it says:

"Could not install app, testflight is currently unavailable. Try again later".

This makes no sense. I tried recreating the developer profiles, I tried it on different devices with different account... always the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have by any chance any other install of the app remaining on the device? As far as i can remember i had the same issue with a device, which had an wireless distributed adHoc build installed

Comment: @MaximilianKörner I deleted the Xcode build before trying testlight...

Comment: answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30801899/294884

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re-downloaded the distribution profile for the app and re-archived the app. Now TestFlight works. Make sure that you select a Distribution profile (not Development)

---

Full description with pictures ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801899/294884

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with one application for internal users... This worked for me:

1. Go to Prerelease -> Builds
2. Turn Off Beta Testing
3. Refresh testflight at your device (Build will appear as unavailable)
4. Turn On Beta Testing
5. Refresh Testflight at your device and install

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Same error. My provisioning file was **inactive** in iOS developer portal as my certificate was **revoked** by other developer. I'd to **activate** the provisioning file with new certificate (exported from keychain by that very developer). So, I'd to use these new provisioning and cert to archive my app.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me. I had the problem, that I couldn't update the gems version (an earlier version was already installed) with the same error message.

Turns out, re-inviting the affected user solves the problem.