# TestFlight is currently unavailable. Try again later

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

Yesterday I created an app with a new certificate and uploaded it to iTunes Connect. I invited 2 friends to internal tests and they accept the invite and downloaded the TestFlight App on iPad and iPhone. They can see the app but get the following message:

"TestFlight is currently unavailable. Try again later."

On [System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) from Apple I can see it runs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Full answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30801899/294884

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267449/ios-8-testflight-does-not-install-app) helped me.

> "I re-downloaded the distribution profile for the app and re-archived the app. Now TestFlight works. Make sure that you select a Distribution profile (not Development)" - answered Jun 17 at 20:11 by [Alessandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197044/alessandro)

Answer (score 2):

We got this error and continued to "Try Again" for 14 hours.  We kept trying all the things found on Google such as checking expired provisioning profiles.  What solved it for us was expiring the last build that was upload just before this started to happen.

Here are some other related details:

The problematic build took an exceptional long time to process before we were notified by Apple that it was available.

[Apple System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) reported that test flight was having issues during the time that we uploaded the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just try after sometime. When I tried to download after 1 hour I could download the app.

Answer (score -9):

The error message

```
"TestFlight is currently unavailable. Try again later."
```

means that TestFlight is currently not available, and that you should try whatever you tried to do again at a later time.

You might take the opportunity to think about whether any error messages that you display to your users are clear enough.

Comment: This answer is wrong, gnash.  The message in question appears when there is a cert problem.  (ie, the message text, from Apple, is totally incorrect.)  There are a number of dupe questions about this.